# D3 world map jumps around when dragging

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I'm trying to make a world map in Vue which I can drag to move around, and zoom in. I've been trying to use D3, however I can't get it to work properly as every time I drag the map it jumps to the bottom right of the page and I can't figure out why for the life of me. The following is an example where you can see the map jump the second I start dragging.

[image]

All documentation and stackoverflow content I can find is using an older version of `d3` which uses a completely different syntax and i can't find any good solutions to the problem other than someone mentioning that I need to somehow calculate the zoom.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<template>
  <div class="map full-width" ref="map">
    <svg class="canvas" :viewBox="`0, 0, ${defaultWidth}, ${defaultHeight}`">
      <g class="graphic"></g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

import { select } from 'd3-selection'
import { transition } from 'd3-transition' // required somehow..
import { transform } from 'd3-transform'
import { geoPath, geoNaturalEarth1 } from 'd3-geo'
import { zoom } from 'd3-zoom'
import { easeCubicInOut } from 'd3-ease'
import { drag } from 'd3-drag'

import json from 'assets/world.json'
import style from 'assets/style.js'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'WorldMap',
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    maxHeight: {
      type: Number,
      default: 500,
    },
    zoomFactor: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0.2,
      validator: (value) => value > 0.0 && value <= 1.0,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    map() {
      return select('.map')
    },
    graphic() {
      return select('.canvas')
    },
    path() {
      return geoPath().projection(this.projection)
    },
    projection() {
      return geoNaturalEarth1().fitSize(
        [this.defaultWidth, this.defaultHeight],
        json
      )
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: zoom().on('zoom', this.onZoom),
      defaultWidth: 950,
      defaultHeight: 550,
      lastTransform: { x: 0, y: 0 },
    }
  },
  watch: {
    data(val) {
      this.renderChart(val)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    renderChart(val) {
      let prefix = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(8)
      let count = 0

      this.graphic
        .on('wheel', this.onMouseScroll)
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, 0)`)
        .call(drag().on('drag', this.onDrag))
        .select('g')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', this.path)
        .attr('fill', style.secondary())
        .attr('stroke', style.primary())
        .attr('stroke-width', '0.7px')
        .attr('class', () => {
          return 'country'
        })
        .attr('id', () => {
          return `country-${prefix}-${count++}`
        })
        .on('mouseover', this.onMouseOver.bind(this))
        .on('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave.bind(this))
    },
    onMouseOver(event, element) {
      this.graphic
        .selectAll('.country')
        .filter(function () {
          return this.id != event.target.id
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('opacity', 0.5)

      this.graphic.select(event.target.id).transition().duration(200)
    },
    onMouseLeave(event, element) {
      this.graphic
        .selectAll('.country')
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('opacity', 1)
    },
    onMouseScroll(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      const scrollDirection = event.deltaY > 0 ? 'down' : 'up'
      if (scrollDirection === 'down') {
        this.zoomOut()
      } else {
        this.zoomIn()
      }
    },
    onDrag(event) {
      const graphic = this.graphic
      const matrix = graphic.node().transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix

      console.log([matrix.e, matrix.f], [event.x, event.y])

      const x = event.x
      const y = event.y

      graphic.attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})`)
    },
    onZoom(event) {
      this.graphic
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .ease(easeCubicInOut)
        .attr('transform', event.transform)
    },
    zoomIn() {
      console.log('Zooming in', this.zoomFactor)
      this.zoom.scaleBy(this.graphic, 1 + this.zoomFactor)
    },
    zoomOut() {
      console.log('Zooming out')
      this.zoom.scaleBy(this.graphic, 1 - this.zoomFactor)
    },
    resetZoom() {
      console.log('Resetting zoom scale.')
      this.lastTransform = { x: 0, y: 0 }
      this.zoom.scaleTo(this.graphic, 1)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart()
  },
})
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.map
  overflow: hidden
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450689/jumping-behavior-when-dragging-groups-of-elements-using-d3-drag) post. Turns out I had to be using `dx` and `dy` instead of `x`, and `y`. The final code looked like this:

```
onDrag(event) {
  const graphic = this.graphic.select('g')
  const matrix = graphic.node().transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix
  const [x, y] = [matrix.e + event.dx, matrix.f + event.dy]
  graphic.attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})`)
}
```